# ContentValues entry is being converted to NULL

Tags: android, sqlite

I am having some trouble with `ContentValues` for input to a database in my program that is proving to be quite difficult to understand. I have a `ContentValues` object which I add about 50 or so entries to and everything works great, except for one entry which is stored as "null". Based on the LogCat output, I know for a fact that the data going into the the `ContentValues` is not null.

**The relevant code:**

```
if (database.isOpen() && !database.isReadOnly()) { //Check that the database is open and not read only
    Log.d(TAG, "Entry string: " + data.getEntryString());
    Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues(); //Create a new ContentValues object to store key value pairs for insertion
    //Various values.put() calls...
    values.put(Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING, data.getEntryString()); //Should put the String "Something"

    Log.d(TAG, "Entry string from values: " + values.getAsString(Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING));
    //Proceed with database insert here
}
```

And the LogCat responses:

```
07-27 08:58:47.909: D/Handler(18020): Entry string: Something 
07-27 08:58:47.909: D/Handler(18020): Key: Entry_String 
07-27 08:58:47.909: D/Handler(18020): Entry string from values: null
```

I have checked over the code several times and I can find no explanation for this. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This is possibly a stupid question, but have you tried to see if it would work if you assigned `data.getEntryString()` to a `String` prior to `values.put`

Comment: Given how this is behaving, I don't consider anything stupid. I just tried that, the string receives the data just fine, much as LogCat does.

Comment: hrm.. odd, I may be overlooking something but I don't see anything wrong with your code. I'll have to keep checking back to see your solution.

Comment: I know the feeling...I feel like its on par with having i++ not work...I appreciate you looking though.

Comment: Have you double checked you're not using duplicate key names?

Comment: Also, data.getEntryString() is a string right? Not a CharSequence or something that LogCat might treat as a string but ContentValues.getAsString might not like?

Comment: I double checked all the key values, everything checks out. Also, it is definitely a String.

Answer (score 2):

I also had this problem.

My case was because I used `ContentValue` in the unit test. `ContentValue` is an android component and it should be used under android environment, but I used it in unit test which doesn't have android implementation. Therefore, when I called `contentValue.put(key, value)` and `contentValue.get(key)`, nothing happened due to the empty implementation.

I'm not sure if you run your code in unit test or other without android implementation. Maybe my solution can give you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this is still bugging me. So in my head I keep going back to `put(String, String)`. Could you ease my mind by trying the following?

```
if (database.isOpen() && !database.isReadOnly()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Entry string: " + data.getEntryString());
    Log.d(TAG, "Key: " + Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING);

    String entryKey = Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING;
    String entryValue = data.getEntryString();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(entryKey, entryValue);

    Log.d(TAG, "Entry string from values: " + values.getAsString(Helper.COLUMN_ENTRY_STRING));
}
```

Comment: No such luck. entryKey and entryValue have the expected values but when I retrieve the value from values, either with entryKey or the stored Column key, in both cases I get null.